# Can concrete class delegate the method implementation to child class?

Tags: c#, class

I have a **concrete** top-class FooBase and an **interface** IFoo:

```
public class FooBase
{
    //some code
}

public interface IFoo
{
    void DoBar();
}
```

every child-classes FooChild implements and extends both:

```
public class FooChild : FooBase, IFoo
{
    public void DoBar()
    {
        //some implementation
    }
}
```

Can concrete FooBase **define the signature of an empty method** in order to **delegate the implementation** to child-classes as IFoo interface does?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/polymorphism

Comment: Don't take this personally; a downvote just means that the question is considered less useful for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways in which a base class can allow or force it's inheritors to implement the desired signature:

##### 1. Virtual method (allows to implement)

```
public interface IFoo { void DoBar(); }
public class Foo : IFoo { public virtual void DoBar() { /*Default impl. */ }
public class FooChild : Foo { public override void DoBar() { /* Child impl. */ }
```

##### 2. Abstract method (forces to implement)

```
public interface IFoo { void DoBar(); }
public abstract class FooBase : IFoo { public abstract void DoBar(); }
public class FooChild : FooBase { public override void DoBar() { /* Child impl. */ }
```

##### 3. Abstract separated method (forces to implement, no direct logical attachment to the interface)

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoBar();
}
public abstract class FooBase : IFoo
{
    public void DoBar() { DoBarRelatedWork(); }
    protected abstract void DoBarRelatedWork();
}
public class FooChild : FooBase
{
    public override void DoBarRelatedWork() { /* Child impl. */ }
}
```